# Google Play navigation style

Tags: android, android-view, android-navigation

How would I create an android app with Google Play's navigation style? I mean how many activity there are? The user can go from one page to any other page endlessly (like when you browse app), you can return back to previous pages, and it even cache some view! 
Is it a webview trick?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Here is what you need. You may use just one activity, or more when you navigate deeper in your app.

It's not a webview trick. It's more of how you manage the fragment backstack.

Comment: lets puts aside the drawer menu, can you elaborate the fragment backstack?

Comment: Look at Implement Back Navigation for Fragments